# Can one file be owned by two RPM packages?

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

Below commands show that one file is owned by two packages. Is there something wrong or is this an expected/acceptable behaviour with RPM packages?

```
$rpm -qf /bin/ls
coreutils-8.4-46.el6.x86_64
coreutils-8.4-47.el6.x86_64

$ rpm -qa|grep 'coreutils-8'
coreutils-8.4-46.el6.x86_64
coreutils-8.4-47.el6.x86_64

$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.10 (Santiago)
```

Comment: Found a related [article](https://pagure.io/packaging-committee/issue/138)

Comment: I'd nitpick and say that you have two *versions* of one *package* installed -- not the potential interpretation of "one file owned by *two different packages*"

Comment: Thanks - agreed. So, is that an acceptable/expected practice ?

Comment: I'm impressed & confused as to how you managed to come to this state; what do you use to install/manage packages on this system? rpm? yum? Did you do anything recently with the coreutils package?

Comment: yum. Its an old server. If its not a good thing, I need to dig for more details.

Comment: It'd be interesting to see if they were installed around the same time, with something like: `rpm -q --queryformat='%{NAME} %{INSTALLTIME}\n' coreutils`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91511/discussion-between-penguin-and-jeff-schaller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No, a file cannot be owned by two **rpm** packages
2. You have two versions of the same package installed. You need to solve that issue.

Personally I have already encountered this some times when updating some packages and then the server is powered off, so data is incomplete on disk. You can try repairing the rpmdb:

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

If you have two packages installed even after rpm db rebuild , you could try just removing both and then reinstalling the one you want.

Comment: You can remove just one package when you specify full NEVRA, i.e. "rpm -e coreutils-8.4-46.el6.x86_64" This will remove the old package and keep the new one.